# bootstrap table width size and colspan

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

table width doesn't work when i use colspan.
i need colspan. and width size like 100px; or 10%
without colspan bottom source code width size works.
how do i edit? may i ask?
help please.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  table {
table-layout: fixed;
word-wrap: break-word;
width: 30%;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2">abc</td>
 </tr>
  <tr class="table table-bordered">
      <td style="width: 10%;" /td>1</td>
      <td style="width: 20%;" /td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like this way you need **https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/hhjoo40b/1/** or clear your point how you want..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      table {
            width: 100%;
            border:1px solid;
     }

     td{
        border:1px solid;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2">abc</td>
 </tr>
  <tr >
      <td style="width: 40%;">1</td>
      <td style="width: 60%;">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have changed it now, notice that i have taken away the table layout:fixed tag and it worked